# Duda sobre las métricas entrenando un modelo de segmentación semántica

Tags: python, model, inteligencia-artificial, keras

Estoy entrenando un modelo de segmentación semántica con el siguiente código:

```
!pip install segmentation-models
!pip install tensorflow==2.8.3
!pip install keras==2.8
import glob
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import segmentation_models as sm
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)
#print(os.listdir("membrane/train"))

#Resizing images is optional, CNNs are ok with large images
SIZE_X = 256 #Resize images (height  = X, width = Y)
SIZE_Y = 256

#Capture training image info as a list
train_images = []

for directory_path in glob.glob("/gdrive/My Drive/swinyseg/images"):
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.jpg")):
        print(img_path)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        train_images.append(img)
        #train_labels.append(label)
#Convert list to array for machine learning processing
train_images = np.array(train_images)

#Capture mask/label info as a list
train_masks = []
for directory_path in glob.glob("/gdrive/My Drive/swinyseg/GTmaps"):
    for mask_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.png")):
        print(mask_path)
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, 0)
        mask = cv2.resize(mask, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X))
        #mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        train_masks.append(mask)
        #train_labels.append(label)
#Convert list to array for machine learning processing
train_masks = np.array(train_masks)

#Use customary x_train and y_train variables
X = train_images
Y = train_masks
Y = np.expand_dims(Y, axis=3) #May not be necessary.. leftover from previous code


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# preprocess input
x_train = preprocess_input(x_train)
x_val = preprocess_input(x_val)
# define model
sm.set_framework('tf.keras')
sm.framework()
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE)
model.compile('Adam', loss=sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=[sm.metrics.iou_score],)

print(model.summary())
# fit model
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float32)
y_val = y_val.astype(np.float32)
model.fit(
   x=x_train,
   y=y_train,
   batch_size=32,
   epochs=2000,
   verbose=1,
   validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

El problema es que obtengo las siguiente métricas en las primeras épocas:

```
Epoch 1/2000
170/170 - 106s 498ms/step - loss: -1012.5895 - iou_score: 44.0803 - val_loss: -17332306.0000 - val_iou_score: 138.4283
Epoch 2/2000
170/170 - 82s 482ms/step - loss: -4921.5527 - iou_score: 135.3752 - val_loss: -4955.8853 - val_iou_score: 118.3342
Epoch 3/2000
170/170 - 87s 514ms/step - loss: -12791.7627 - iou_score: 135.7625 - val_loss: -18663.5859 - val_iou_score: 135.3642
Epoch 4/2000
170/170 - 83s 486ms/step - loss: -24989.0703 - iou_score: 133.2874 - val_loss: -44462.9453 - val_iou_score: 138.4401
Epoch 5/2000
170/170 - 87s 514ms/step - loss: -40133.1758 - iou_score: 134.3614 - val_loss: -63428.4062 - val_iou_score: 138.5109
```

Y sigue así hasta la época 20.
Según lo que entiendo no debería tener sentido que val_loss sea negativa y tan grande y que iou sea siempre mayor que 1. No puedo probar el modelo todavía ya que lo estoy ejecutando en colab y va muy lento, por eso me gustaría detectar cualquier error sin necesidad de esperar las 2000 épocas. ¿Qué es lo que podría estar fallando?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.